# UICollectionView: How to handle reloadData() and performBatchUpdates() together

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have `UIRefreshControl` whose selector calls `collectionView.reloadData()`. My collectionView uses paginated API to load data on while scrolling. Hence I do `collectionView.insertItems(at:indexpaths)` to add next paginated data.

I am facing a problem when I scroll the collectionView to get next paginated data and refresh the collectionView. Hence the reload and insert will be called together, app crashes with the error message `

> "attempt to insert item 9 into section 0, but there are only 9 items
>   in section 0 after the update"

`
How do I handle such situation gracefully?

Comment: Why reload data is required when you are inserting row manually?

Comment: reloadData() is called when I refresh the collection view using UIRefreshControl. Refresh is user initiated. Hope you understood the question

Comment: I think problem is with datalist, which you are using to populate collectionview. You need to update datalist before reload.

Comment: It works fine if reloadData() and insertItem() user flow done seperately